# Multiple Forms, One save call and multiple input elements with same name

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Scenario:-
I have a jsp(say A) in which I have included even more jsps(say P,Q,R,S). In P,Q,R and S I have created one form each. On hitting the main save button I am sending an ajax request where in I am serializing all 4 forms (of jsps P,Q,R,S) and then sending this serialized content in the ajax's data. And on controller I am retrieving this serialized form content in my object as say p,q,r,s.

Actual Problem:- 
On all the 4 forms I have a separate commandName, but in each form I am maintaining a hidden input element with name "id". On seeing the ajax request in firebug from console, all the ids are being posted absolutely correctly(as in they are different say 1101,1102,1103,1104 of P,Q,R,S form respectively) but when it reaches my controller the id that is contained in all the objects(p,q,r,s) is same(1101 for P,Q,R and S). Couldn't find the reason for this. Any help is appreciated..

```
<form:form id="A" commandName="objectA">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1101" />
</form:form>

<form:form id="B" commandName="objectB">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1102" />
</form:form>

<form:form id="C" commandName="objectC">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1103" />
</form:form>

<form:form id="D" commandName="objectD">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1104" />
</form:form>
```

Then in my ajax request I am sending the data as

```
url  : "myController/myRequestMapping",
data : $("#A").serialize()+"&"
      +$("#B").serialize()+"&"
      +$("#C").serialize()+"&"
      +$("#D").serialize(),
```

And on controller I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myRequestMapping")
public void myFunction(AClass a,BClass b,CClass c,DClass d){
  System.out.println("A's ID is:"+a.getId());    //Prints 1101
  System.out.println("B's ID is:"+b.getId());    //Prints 1101 instead of 1102
  System.out.println("C's ID is:"+c.getId());    //Prints 1101 instead of 1103
  System.out.println("D's ID is:"+d.getId());    //Prints 1101 instead of 1104
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

If all form has same input element, then create a dto class like:

```
public class Form {

    private Long id;

    public Form(){}

        //getters and setters
}
```

and a `AllForms` class to hold all `Form` instances like:

```
public class AllForms extends ArrayList<Form> {}
```

then in js make array of all form contents:

```
var myarray = [
        {id: $('#A').find('input[name="id"]').val()},
        {id: $('#B').find('input[name="id"]').val()},
        {id: $('#C').find('input[name="id"]').val()},
        {id: $('#D').find('input[name="id"]').val()}
        ];

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(myarray);
```

Then in AJAX request do like:

```
url  : "myController/myRequestMapping",
data : jsonStr
```

in controller retrive like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="//myController/myRequestMapping", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody AllForms process(@RequestBody AllForms allForms){

    System.out.println(allForms);
    return allForms;
}
```

---

OR else alternative is:

JS POST like:

```
$.post("myController/myRequestMapping",{jsonStr : jsonStr},function(e) {
        console.log('success: '+e);
    }, "json");
```

and handler method like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myController/myRequestMapping", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String process(@RequestParam String jsonStr){
      System.out.println(jsonStr);

      //convert here Form instance from jsonStr

    return jsonStr;
}
```